# When making a shield.io badge, is there a way to find the right way to reference a logo name?

Tags: badge, shields.io

I just started trying to use shield.io badges today. I'm a little confused.

When I needed to use the C++ logo in a label I used the following request:

```
https://img.shields.io/badge/C++-%2300599C.svg?&style=for-the-badge&logo=c%2B%2B&logoColor=white
```

Which yielded a label with a logo, as intended.

I expected it to be `logo=c-plus-plus` and through trial and error I eventually found out that I should use the encoding for the `+` sign, `%2B`.

Now I can't find the logo for Selenium, although it is clearly on the `simple-vector` list (https://simpleicons.org/icons/selenium.svg) and there's nothing odd about this name, no spaces or signs, so I don't know how to find it. `logo=selenium` should work but it doesn't.

This is what I'm trying:
`https://img.shields.io/badge/selenium-%2343B02A.svg?&style=for-the-badge&logo=selenium&logoColor=white`
And what I get is a label without logo.
Any thoughts?

PS: I don't have enough reputation to post images so I can't include the resulting images in the text but you can copy the link to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The link that you pasted gives the link now correctly with image

[Github link which has most of the shields that you people would require](https://github.com/alexandresanlim/Badges4-README.md-Profile)

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the url structure fully `https://img.shields.io/badge/<LABEL>-<MESSAGE>-<COLOR>`. The color property seems wrong.

For Selenium logo request could be like this (without message)
`https://img.shields.io/badge/selenium-43B02A.svg?&style=for-the-badge&logo=selenium&logoColor=white`.

The parameter for the C++ logo should be `cplusplus` and the color should be `00599C` like `https://img.shields.io/badge/C++-00599C.svg?&style=for-the-badge&logo=cplusplus&logoColor=white`

https://shields.io/

https://simpleicons.org/